# get a sparse df of a column with lists of varying length and ensure the proper merge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have one pandas dataframe like this:

```
>>> df1

        col_1   col_2    labels
1        aaa     abc     [71020]
2        bbb     cde     [77085]
3        ccc     efg     [36415]
4        ddd     ghi     [99213, 99287]
5        eee     ijk     [99233, 71020, 36415]
```

and another dataframe like this(I got this df using [sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) on `labels` column of above `df1`):

```
>>> df2

   71020  77085  36415  99213  99287  99233
1    1      0      0      0      0      0
2    0      1      0      0      0      0
3    0      0      1      0      0      0
4    0      0      0      1      1      0
5    1      0      1      0      0      1
```

and I would now like to merge(or right join) `df2` on `df2`, with keys being values from `labels` column and all the column names of `df2`, like shown below:

```
        col_1   col_2    labels                   71020  77085  36415  99213  99287  99233
1        aaa     abc     [71020]                     1      0      0      0      0      0
2        bbb     def     [77085]                     0      1      0      0      0      0
3        ccc     ghi     [36415]                     0      0      1      0      0      0
4        ddd     jkl     [99213, 99287]              0      0      0      1      1      0
5        eee     mno     [99233, 71020, 36415]       1      0      1      0      0      1
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output can be achieved (may be easier) if you create `df2` from Pandas, as follows:

We create `df2a` from `df1` `labels` column as follows:

```
# Assuming your `labels` column contain real list rather than string looks like list.  
# If not, we can convert the string to real list first
import ast
df1['labels'] = df1['labels'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

# Then, create the dummy table by Pandas
df2a = df['labels'].explode().astype(str).str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).max()

# Optionally convert the column labels back to integer from string
df2a.columns = df2a.columns.astype(int)
```

Result:

```
print(df2a)

   36415  71020  77085  99213  99233  99287
0      0      1      0      0      0      0
1      0      0      1      0      0      0
2      1      0      0      0      0      0
3      0      0      0      1      0      1
4      1      1      0      0      1      0
```

Then, we can join with `df1` to get the desired output:

```
df1.join(df2a)
```

**Result:**

```
  col_1 col_2                 labels  36415  71020  77085  99213  99233  99287
0   aaa   abc                [71020]      0      1      0      0      0      0
1   bbb   cde                [77085]      0      0      1      0      0      0
2   ccc   efg                [36415]      1      0      0      0      0      0
3   ddd   ghi         [99213, 99287]      0      0      0      1      0      1
4   eee   ijk  [99233, 71020, 36415]      1      1      0      0      1      0
```

Comment: so, Mr @SeaBean, there's no way to ensure that the join/merge is happening for right row, instead of relying on just index?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala  Matching by index will already ensure they are aligned.    The process we generate `df2a`, it will keep the original index of `df1`.  Thus, when joining back, both are based on the same set of index.  No problem.